# Open a local PDF file on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm running create-react-app, and I want to open a local PDF file stored inside my repo with a relative path.

```
<a href="../file.pdf" target="_blank">
    <button name="Click here" />
</a>
```

After I click it, it takes me to `localhost:3000/file.pdf`. How do I open up a new window with a PDF?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote after the ".pdf", yes?

Comment: Just change your html with...
`<a href="../file.pdf" target="_blank">Click here</a>`

Comment: @OfirBaruch, haha simple typo on my end. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to host your local pdf file to make it open inside your application.

Use **SimpleHTTPServer** for installing a server and run it wherever your pdf file is located.

After successfully running the SimpleHTTPServer, you can check it by opening the pdf file inside your web browser. If the pdf file is getting opened inside your current browser than hurray your file has been hosted and now it can be opened inside your application.

Regards

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make sure that the path to the file.pdf file is correct.
If file's path is true. You write on project from following code.

Actually, you should not use the button again after the  tag. I think you edit your code by this.

```
<a href="../file.pdf" target="_blank">
    <label>Click here</label>
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="../file.pdf" target="_blank">
    Click here
</a>
```

Try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the type

```
<a href="../file.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="../file.pdf" target="_blank">
    <button name="Click here" />
</a>
```

Comment: This wont work right? He is trying to access parent folder from its local hosting folder.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You had a syntax error with the double quotes before you edited your post.